# c - How to check EOF when read() on FIFO

Tags: c, linux, ipc, eof, fifo

In a client-server program, need check **EOF** for `read()` on a `FIFO`?

**Questions:**

- Does **EOF** in FIFO return `0`, or `-1` with errno set?
- Does the rule also apply to other IPC facilities?

---

**@Update**

I still found the result wield, so need to continue ask about it.

---

### Following are the source code:

**cs_fifo.h:**

```
// fifo header
#ifndef _CS_FIFO
#define _CS_FIFO

#define CLIENT_DATA_SIZE 2
#define SERVER_DATA_SIZE 10

#define SERVER_FIFO_PATH "/tmp/server_fifo"

#define CLIENT_COUNT 3

#endif
```

**fifo_server.c:**

```
// client - server fifo, server part,
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include "cs_fifo.h"

int fifo_server() {
    int flag;
    int fd;

    char buf[CLIENT_DATA_SIZE];

    // remove fifo, before create
    remove(SERVER_FIFO_PATH);

    // create fifo
    mode_t mode = 0644;
    if((flag = mkfifo(SERVER_FIFO_PATH, mode)) == -1) {
        printf("error while mkfifo(): %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }
    printf("server fifo created, path: %s\n", SERVER_FIFO_PATH);

    // open for read
    if((fd = open(SERVER_FIFO_PATH, O_RDONLY)) == -1) {
        printf("error while open(): %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(-1);
    }

    // loop to receive data from client,
    while(1) {
        // read from fifo
        if((flag = read(fd, buf, CLIENT_DATA_SIZE)) == -1) {
            printf("error while read(): %s\n", strerror(errno));
            exit(0);
        } else if(flag == 0) { // no data
            printf("no data\n");
            sleep(1);
            continue;
        }
        // data received,
        printf("receive data: %s\n", buf);

        // send data back to client's fifo,
        // TODO
    }

    // remove fifo, after finish using,
    remove(SERVER_FIFO_PATH);

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    return fifo_server();
}
```

**fifo_client.c:**

```
// client - server fifo, client pool part,
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include "cs_fifo.h"

int fifo_client_pool() {
    int flag;
    int server_fd;

    char data[CLIENT_DATA_SIZE];

    int i = 0;
    pid_t cpid;
    char identity;

    // open for write
    if((server_fd= open(SERVER_FIFO_PATH, O_WRONLY)) == -1) {
        printf("error while open(): %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(-1);
    }

    // create child processes as clients,
    while(i < CLIENT_COUNT) {
        switch(cpid=fork()) {
            case -1: // failed
                printf("error while fork(): %s\n", strerror(errno));
                exit(errno);
            case 0: // success, child process goes here
                printf("child process created, pid [%d], parent pid [%d]\n",(int)getpid(), (int)getppid());
                identity = i + 65; // start from 'A'

                // prepare data
                data[0] = identity;
                data[1] = '\0';

                // write to fifo
                if((flag = write(server_fd, data, CLIENT_DATA_SIZE)) == -1) {
                    printf("[%c] error while write(): %s\n", identity, strerror(errno));
                    _exit(-1);
                }
                printf("[%c] send data to server\n", identity);

                _exit(0);

                break;
            default: // success, parent process goes here
                // sleep a while,
                sleep(1);
                break;
        }

        i++;
    }

    if((flag = close(server_fd)) != 0) {
        printf("error while close(): %s\n", strerror(errno));
    }

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    return fifo_client_pool();
}
```

---

**Compile:**

Server: `gcc -Wall fifo_server.c -o server`

Client: `gcc -Wall fifo_client_pool.c -o client_pool`

**Execute:**

First start server: `./server`

Then start client pool: `./client_pool`

**Result:**

- Server start, and blocks before client start.
- Then client start, and server receive 1 request from each of the 3 clients, that's 3 in total.
- Then all client processes terminated, then server's read() continue return `0` without blocked.

---

**The future question is:**

- After all clients terminated, shouldn't server's `read()` block? Since it's in blocking mode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*All* reads from a descriptor where `read` returns zero means "closed" or "end".

If you have a blocking descriptor (the default) then `read` will block if there's currently nothing to read. If the descriptor is non-blocking then `read` returns `-1` with `errno` set to `EAGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK` if there's nothing to read.

Comment: In my program, the `read()` return with `0`, it's in blocking mode, the reader is still open, but all writers are closed, is this normal or wield?

Comment: @EricWang When a pipe (FIFO) is closed from the other end, when there's nothing more to read, then `read` will return zero and you should close your end. And for a blocking descriptor, `read` simply will block (not return) until there's something to read.

Comment: I updated the question with code & more description, because the the testing result seems a little wield, could u also take a look at that, thx.

Comment: @EricWang If `read` returns zero it means you're done receiving, you won't receive anything more. So you should close the descriptor and exit the loop you're in, not continue hope there will come more because it won't. When `read` returns zero it doesn't mean "no data" it means "end of file" or "connection closed" or "no more data in pipe", it's not a temporary lack of data, it's a permanent end of the data stream.

Comment: So, for `read()` the so called `blocking mode` will block only when there are still open write end, otherwise it will return 0, means EOF.

Comment: Yes. If the other end of the pipe is closed, the pipe is closed, there's no more data. So read() unblocks, and returns 0 so you can act on that fact.

Comment: @nos Ok, after `EOF` then I started the client again, then server receive data again, interesting design for FIFO, really tricky!

Comment: Yes - I wouldn't particularly recommend using a named fifo for multiple clients though.

Comment: @nos Yeah, I am just learning about the mechanism of FIFO, not using it in production.