# named fifo C issue

Tags: c, fifo, named

I have this C code:

```
#define BUFSIZE 256

int main ( int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fdIn;
    int fdOut;

    if( argc != 3)
    {
        perror("argument error");
        exit(1);
    }

    if( (fdIn = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY ) )<0)
    {
        perror("pipe input error open");
        exit(1);
    }

    if( (fdOut = open(argv[2], O_WRONLY ) )<0)
    {
        perror("pipe input error open");
        exit(1);
    }


    int c = 2;
    while(c--)
    {
        char var1[BUFSIZE];
        char var2[BUFSIZE];
        char string[100];

        memset(var1, 0, sizeof(var1));
        memset(var2, 0, sizeof(var2));
        memset(string, 0, sizeof(string));

        if( readLine(fdIn, var1, sizeof(var1)) == 0)
        {
            printf("exit1\n");
            exit(0);
        }

        if( readLine(fdIn, var2, sizeof(var2)) == 0)
        {
            printf("exit2\n");
            exit(0);
        }

        removeNewLine(var1);
        removeNewLine(var2);

        printf("%s\n",var1);
        printf("%s\n",var2);

        int n = atoi(var1);
        int m = atoi(var2);

        if (n!=0 && m % n == 0 ) {

            sprintf(string,"multiple\n");

        }
        else{
            sprintf(string,"negative\n");

        }

        printf("%s", string);
        writeLine(fdOut, string, strlen(string));
    }
    close(fdOut);
    close(fdIn);
    exit(0);
}
```

This program accepts 2 inputs: first is input fifo's name and second is output fifo's name.
This program does this: reads in the input fifo 2 numbers and then establishes if second number is multiple of first number and then writes on output fifo "multiple" or "negative".
This all for 2 times; my problem is when it executed the second loop where the first `ReadLine` returns 0 and it prints `exit1`.
the program should not stop on the `readLine` pending content in the FIFO?

functions used in the program:

```
int readLine( int fd, char* str, int bufferSize)
{
    return readToDel(fd, '\n', str, bufferSize);
}

int readToDel( int fd, char delimiter, char* str, int bufferSize)
{
    int n;
    int byteLetti =0;
    int index=0;



    do /* Read characters until NULL or end-of-input */
    {

        if( (n = read (fd, str+index, 1)) < 0)
        {
            perror("Errore: lettura dal file descriptor fallita");
            exit(1);
        }
        byteLetti+=n;

    }
    while (n > 0 && *(str+index++) != delimiter && index < bufferSize);     
    return byteLetti; /* Return false if end-of-input */
}
```

For testing this program I do like this:
open first terminal and I write in the input fifo in this way:

```
echo "4" > input 
echo "8" > input
```

then open other terminal and I execute the program in this way:

```
./program input output
```

and when the program is blocked on `writeLine(fdOut, string, strlen(string));` ( because there isn't reader on output fifo) open other terminal and I do : `cat output`

and the I get(based on those input):

```
multiple
exit1
```

and I dont understand why.
should not wait until more input on input fifo?

Comment: There is EOF because there is no more data and no writes into pipe possible because it isn't opened for writing anywhere. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/34327108/744720

Comment: this line: `perror("argument error");` is rather useless to the user of the program.  Suggest something similar to: `fprintf( stderr, "Usage %s <input file> <output file>\n", argv[0] );`

Comment: regarding these lines: `if( (fdOut = open(argv[2], O_WRONLY ) )<0)
    {
        perror("pipe input error open");
        exit(1);
    }`,  the text in the call to `perror()` is not correct, (probably a copy-and-paste error)